# compact C# expression for multiple consecutive non-nested breaking ifs

Tags: c#, coding-style

I currently have

```
if A {
    //code
    return;
}
if B {
    //code
    return;
}
...
```

Is there a simple way to express this for a large number of conditions?

The goal in this case is validation of something that can fail in different ways, which all require different handling.
I then expect this block of code to be called again later, when whatever condition has just been resolved will fail, and it will slip through the tests until it meets another condition and is rejected in a new and exciting way.

I was really just hoping for something on the level of a switch statement (in terms of simplicity and ease of use) but I guess that doesn't exist...

Comment: There is definitely no way that will require writing less code. What exactly is it that you believe would benefit from simplification?

Comment: @Jon: To express that they are all "alternative cases" in some sense, as a switch statement does, since only one will ever be executed. But it seems the answer is no, not really.

Comment: sharp beginner: "alternative" as in "there is no way ever that `A && B == true`" or as in "I have a bunch of `return`s in there which say that there's only one winner"?

Comment: @Jon: There are ways that multiple conditions will be true, but I've ordered them in such a way that the first one to test is the one I want handled.

Comment: Then use `else if` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, but it's really hard to guide you without knowing more about the types of conditions you have and what the code in each one does... if there are similarities, you can probably find ways to abstract those out instead of repeating them (using 'switch' statements, delegates, etc).  If these things are totally unrelated, it won't get any better than what you have shown - except to change latter 'if's to 'else if' and then put a single 'return' at the very end.

Comment: Not similar enough that I can generalize it any more than I already have, and since this is for a training exercise, I'd prefer not to post my code verbatim. I'll just use else if's as you and Ilya have suggested.

Comment: ok.  later you might want to research "c# design patterns" to look for ways to refactor your code that would enable a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your conditions are testing the same value for equality with other values, you can use the [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Note that in C#, unlike C++ or Java, you can use a string as the switch value.

You can use the [?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator but only if your "code" can be expressed as a single expression and they all return the same type. So for example,

```
var user = conditionA ? expressionA :
           conditionB ? expressionB :
           conditionC ? expressionC;
```

It would probably help most though if you say what your actual problem is. It's possible a cleaner approach would be possible through polymorphism, array/dictionary lookups, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately my tests aren't quite that simple. I've updated the question with more info about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use class that inherit an abstract base class `ConditionalAction`, which could look like this:

```
public abstract class ConditionalAction
{
    public abstract bool Condition();
    public abstract void Action();
}
```

A sample class that inherits `ConditionalAction`:

```
public class SampleConditionalAction : ConditionalAction
{
    public override bool Condition()
    {
        // Condition
    }
    public override void Action()
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
List<ConditionalAction> conditionalActions = new List<ConditionalAction>();
conditionalActions.Add(new SampleConditionalAction());
// Add more ConditionalActions...

foreach(ConditionalAction conditionalAction in conditionalActions)
{
    if (conditionalAction.Condition())
        conditionalAction.Action();
}
```

The main place you'd get stuck with this approach is if you need information for your conditions or your actions, but you can build that in by passing in parameters to your constructors of your ConditionalActions.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary<Func<bool>, Action>`. The keys will be the conditions (every one of them a `bool Method()`) and the values will be the pieces of code to execute.

Then you can easily iterate through the keys that meet the codition and execute their values:

```
foreach (pair in dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Key()))
{
    pair.Value();
}
```

Comment: The code to create that dictionary likely isn't going to be any 'simpler' than a big if/else block.  It will definitely though make the code more difficult for a C# beginner to follow/debug.

Comment: @Robert As you said, it depends very much on the requirements. This approach can be useful if there is an advantage to adding/removing conditions dynamically, e.g. loading them from configuration. For a large number of conditions this code is also a little more concise.

Comment: agreed that this a great for dynamically changing coditions

Comment: thanks, But as Robert says, I think this is a little more difficult than what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the conditionals are, the code is doing and the design of the component.

For example, if it's a configuration class that stores a load of settings then I'd have no problem with the above. Conversely if this defines or controls paths of execution in your application then that might suggest a design deficiency. Lots of conditionals or switch statements can be refactored using inheritance or dependency injection for example.

If you have a serious number of conditions and it isn't a config class I would think about your code at a design level, rather than a syntactic one.